# Putting panels in a big Panel

Tags: java

I want to create a Frame with a big panel with flow layout which contains several smaller panels with a given size. I thought I could do like this: (The JFrame is given)

```
private void testLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    add(panel);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setSize(300, 200);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel.add(panel1);
}
```

If I run this, I just get my big panel in gray and I only see a small red square in the top middle of my frame, although I set the size to 300px and 200px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The displayed size of a component is determined by the [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Some layout managers use the value returned by method [getSize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#getSize()) but not any of the ones that you are using in your code.

As you correctly stated, the default layout manager for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` and `FlowLayout` actually uses the value returned by method [getPreferredSize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#getPreferredSize()). Hence,
rather than calling method `setSize`, call `setPreferredSize`. Below code demonstrates. (More explanations after the code.)

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelTst implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Panels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new PanelTst());
    }
}
```

The default layout manager for the [content pane of] [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) is `BorderLayout`. In the code in your question, you are actually adding `panel` to the center of `BorderLayout` which means that it will take up all the available space.

Since you don't set any size for `panel` its size will be determined by the size of its parent. Hence, in my code, above, I explicitly set the size of the `JFrame`. Otherwise, you would only see `panel1`. (I suggest that you modify the above code and see for yourself. Replace `frame.setSize(450, 300);` with `frame.pack();`)

This is how it looks when I run the above code.

[image: screen capture]